# Opening a local or network path in Explorer from browser

Tags: windows, registry, protocols, local, url-scheme

I am trying to open a path in Explorer.exe from the browser. I added a custom protocol:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\filebrowser]
@="File browser"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\filebrowser\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\filebrowser\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\filebrowser\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe\" %1"
```

I am testing with the following link in the browser, which should open C:\Windows in Explorer:

```
<a href = "filebrowser:///parameter1=C:\Windows">Windows folder</a>
```

However, instead of opening C:\Windows folder, Explorer opens Documents folder when I click the link. Somehow it seems that the parameter isn't received correctly by Explorer.exe. If I type **filebrowser:///parameter1=C:\Windows** in Run command window, Explorer opens Windows folder.

How can I open the correct path in Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

For a link like: `<a href = "filebrowser:///C:\Windows">Windows folder</a>`  using the registry script from my previous example, Explorer.exe will be called with **filebrowser:///C%5CWindows** as parameter instead of **C:\Windows**. I worked around this with the following registry script where I replace some strings:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\filebrowser]
@="File browser"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\filebrowser\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\filebrowser\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\filebrowser\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /k set myvar=%1  & call set myvar=%%myvar:filebrowser:///=%% & call set myvar=%%myvar::=:\\%% & call Explorer.exe %%myvar%% & exit"
```

It doesn't seem possible to call Explorer.exe with a path as parameter without running a batch script in cmd or calling other program to do the replacement.

For a network path like **\Host145\Users\Mike\Documents** I can't use backslashes since they will get URL encoded and will be hard to replace in the script. Instead, I am using **#** sign like so: `<a href = "filebrowser:///##Host145#Users#Mike#Documents">Test folder</a>`  and the script will become:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\filebrowser]
@="File browser"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\filebrowser\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\filebrowser\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\filebrowser\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /k set myvar=%1  & call set myvar=%%myvar:filebrowser:///=%% & call set myvar=%%myvar::=:\\%% & call set myvar=%%myvar:#=\\%% & call Explorer.exe %%myvar%% & exit"
```

Comment: No matter what I try 
<a href="filebrowser:///##volume1#Success">Click me</a>
I keep getting documents.
volume1 is mapped network drive to z:
This folder lives inside c:\xampp\htdocs\dev\
but the client has Success mapped from NAS on his pc.

Answer (score 0):

To my that is not working

**cmd /k set myvar=%1  & call set myvar=%%myvar:filebrowser:///=%% & call set myvar=%%myvar::=:\%% & call Explorer.exe %%myvar%% & exit**

change to

**cmd /k set myvar=%1  & call set myvar=%%myvar:filebrowser:///=%% & call set myvar=%%myvar::=:\%% & call start %%myvar%% & exit**

and now is working fine
Test on Windows 11 and 10